# How to create Expressjs API for MongoDB subdocuments?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, rest, subdocument

I am trying to create API for MongoDB nested / subdocuments. But, I am really confused about HTTP Request Method, end-point naming convention and mongoose CRUD methods for subdocuments.
Here is my code:

```
// Create Subdocuments

router.put("/blogs/:blogId/comment", async function (req, res) {
  const blogId = req.params.blogId;
  const { commentText } = req.body;

  const blog = await Blog.findById(blogId);
  blog.comments.push({ commentText });
  const newBlog = await blog.save();

  res.json(newBlog);
});

// Delete Subdocuments

router.put("/blogs/:blogId/comments/:commentId", async function (req, res) {
  const { blogId, commentId } = req.params;
  const blog = await Blog.findById(blogId);
  blog.comments.id(commentId).remove();
  const newBlog = await blog.save();

  res.json(newBlog);
});

// Update Subdocuments

router.put("/blogs/:blogId/comments/:commentId", async function (req, res) {
  const { blogId, commentId } = req.params;
  const blog = await Blog.findById(blogId);
  blog.comments.id(commentId).commentText = req.body.commentText;
  const newBlog = await blog.save();

  res.json(newBlog);
});
```

Please let me know the best approach for array of subdocuments CRUD operations.

Comment: Even though users here can go through all the codes, but it's generally better if you let us know specifically **what is the problem you are facing** or **what errors you encountered**

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial You should have noticed that here in update and delete option, I have written same end point, which will never work. My question is clear. I wanted to know the http method, end point name and mongoose crud methods.

Comment: Create -> Post, Read   -> Get, Update -> Put, Delete -> Delete, e.g. `router.delete()` to delete subdocuments.

Comment: And Patch for partial update.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial Here I am updating Blog document every time to preform CRUD operation for it's comments subdocument.

Comment: [I've created a GIT Repo](https://github.com/balexandre/so65351733) to help in another MongoDB with ExpressJs question some time ago... might be useful for you to see all working...